# Looping across months

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have two tables say A ( Detail table) and B (summary table).

Transactions in table A fall into various months within a year. Table B has some fields defined to correspond to a particular month (as illustrated below). I want a procedure that will fetch records from Table A and update Table B such that the amounts for say month 1 will be summed up in YTDBAL_1,  month 2 will be the sum of month 1 plus  sum of month 2 (YTDBAL2) and so on such that the consecutive month will hold cumulative balances from beginning of year to date (current month).

Sample Data in Table A

```
OFFCD     GLHEAD        YEAR        MONTH       AMOUNT  
010       10101001      2014        01          25,000.00  
010       10101001      2014        01           5,000.00  
010       10101001      2014        02           8,000.00  
010       10101001      2014        02           4,000.00  
010       10101001      2014        03          10,000.00  
010       10101001      2014        04          10,000.00  
010       10101001      2014        05          -4,000.00  
010       10101001      2014        05           3,000.00  
..  
..  
010       10101001      2014        12           1,000.00
```

Expected data in  Table B

```
OFFCD   GLHEAD    YEAR    YTDBAL_1  YTDBAL_2    YTDBAL_3   YTDBAL_4   YTDBAL_5  ..... YTDBAL_12  
010     10101001  2014    30,000    42,000      52,000     62,000     61,000            XXX
```

My procedure below was populating all fields with same amount. How do i make it such that i arrive at above expected result.
NB: The transaction table has more than a million records and I am using Oracle 11g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE rectify_gl_bal(w_year Number)
IS
  CURSOR gl_cur IS
    Select * from nlmstdtl
      where period_year=w_year;

  TYPE gl_array IS TABLE OF gl_cur%ROWTYPE;

  gldtl gl_array;
Begin
  open gl_cur;

  Loop
    Fetch gl_cur bulk collect into gldtl limit 500;
    EXIT WHEN gldtl.count = 0;

    Forall x in 1..gldtl.count
      update nlmst
        set NLMST.YTDBAL_1 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_1 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_2 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_2 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_3 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_3 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_4 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_4 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_5 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_5 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_6 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_6 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_7 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_7 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_8 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_8 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_9 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_9 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_10 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_10 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_11 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_11 + gldtl(x).amount,
            NLMST.YTDBAL_12 =  NLMST.YTDBAL_12 + gldtl(x).amount
        where nlmst.offcd = gldtl(x).offcd and
              nlmst.period_year = gldtl(x).period_year and
              nlmst.glhead = gldtl(x).glhead;
  End Loop;

  commit;
  close gl_cur;
End;
```

Comment: PLease show the table column definitions and what is "gldtl" function?

Comment: It's not quite clear in my mind, but _from your description_, won't a simple `SUM() ... GROUP BY ...`  or `SUM() OVER (PARTITION ...)` do most of the job?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - `gldtl` is a variable in the procedure - the target of the FETCH...BULK COLLECT.

Comment: A stored procedure (PL/SQL) is a wrong tool here as the problem can be solved by a rather simple (YMMV) SQL as demonstrated by @SylvainLeroux. Never underestimate the power of SQL !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It it really required to write a procedure? Can't something like that do the trick:

```
SELECT OFFCD, GLHEAD, YEAR,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH <= 01 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) YTDBAL_1,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH <= 02 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) YTDBAL_2,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH <= 03 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) YTDBAL_3,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH <= 04 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) YTDBAL_4,
  SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH <= 05 THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) YTDBAL_5
  -- and so on up to YTDBAL_12
  -- ...


  FROM A
  GROUP BY OFFCD, GLHEAD, YEAR
```

Producing (given the first 8 rows of your sample data):

```
OFFCD   GLHEAD      YEAR    YTDBAL_1    YTDBAL_2    YTDBAL_3    YTDBAL_4    YTDBAL_5
10      10101001    2014    30000       42000       52000       62000       61000
```

Comment: Thank you Sylvain..that could as well sort me out. I appreciate all your advice on SQL vs PL/SQL procedures.